# Different available keyboard layouts in language bar and Text Services and Input Languages

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, keyboard-layout, language

I don't really know a good way to describe this problem, so please take a look at the picture. There should be something odd about it. [image: ScreenShot]

My problem is that when I install Serbian Latin layout, CJK layouts appear under list of available layouts in the language bar, but not in the Text Services and Input Languages. This is a problem with me because I often use keyboard shortcuts to switch quickly between languages. This way, I need to pres the key combination 4 more times in order to rotate currently selected layout.

Normally when Serbian Latin layout is installed, it doesn't drag CJK layouts together with it. I'm unable to connect start of this behavior to installation of some particular piece of software because I usually don't have Serbian Latin layout installed, since I rarely use it.

When I remove Serbian Latin layout, CJK layouts disappear too.

Is there a way to solve this issue without reinstalling windows?

Comment: Is Serbian part of the Eastern Languages pack? if not then you could simply uninstall the eastern languages maybe then they would not react like this.

Comment: @rzlines It shouldn't be. I'll try with uninstalling Eastern Languages pack.

Comment: @rzlines Can you tell me what should I do  to uninstall Eastern Languages pack? I checked under Region and Language and I don't have any East Asian language installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to remove the phantom layouts by installing the layout in Text Services and Input Languages and removing it. It remains to be seen if this solution is permanent or not.

**EDIT** Finally found out what was causing the issue. Office 2010 installed IMEs for CJK languages and they were in startup. After I removed them from startup, eastern layouts finally stopped appearing

Answer (score 1):

Damn didn't look properly at your screenshot sorry you have 7 installed. Can you try Install/Uninstall Languages (you will find this on the languages tab) and check if CJK are available there then you can manually uninstall them. *(The Eastern Language pack is an XP thing*)

Comment: None of the east Asian languages are on the installed list.

Comment: okay can you check that while you selected the Serbian language these other languages (CJK) or not ticked I've done the same thing on my computer and I its not acting up like the way yours is. Could be that those too have gotten ticked by a freak accident.

Comment: I know that they don't show up on the screenshot but just check it once

Comment: I meant, in Install/Uninstall->Uninstall languages, I only have English (which is the system language) and Serbian Latin (which I need for handwriting recognition).

Answer (score 1):

I did not have those tools in the start-up folder, nor did installation contained IME for CJK languages.

But they were in the 'language proofing tools' (which is a separate setup). And removing them from that install fixed the problem for me:
[image]

Edit: In the end, I also had to edit the registry as described in [This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/199553/self-installing-east-asian-language-set-how-to-remove-asian-languages-from-a-la/234050#234050)