# Self installing East Asian language set. How to remove Asian languages from a language bar?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, input-languages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Different available keyboard layouts in language bar and Text Services and Input Languages](https://superuser.com/questions/187845/different-available-keyboard-layouts-in-language-bar-and-text-services-and-input)

I have the following problem on a Windows 7 machine: a set of languages is automatically self-installed which includes Korean, Chinese, and Japanese languages.

I've tried removing them manually from time to time from a language bar. However this doesn't help and they keep getting reinstalled.

How can I remove them for good?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem on a Windows 7 64-bit machine. I accidently added the Asian language support and was left with three extra keyboard layouts after each restart (KOR, JPN, CHS). This is what I did to fix it:

*Note: please read the whole thing before going step-by-step; you may find that starting with step 7 will be more comfortable for you rather than starting with step 1.*

1. Remove the Korean, Japanese and Chinese keyboards from the keyboard list
2. Press Win-key + R to open the "run" command window
3. Input: `regedit` then press ENTER - this will open the Windows Registry
4. Navigate to the following key:

   ```
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
   ```
5. You will find three items referring to:

   ```
   "c:/program files/common files/microsoft/imei14/shared/imeklmg.exe /uninstall /CHS /log"
   "c:/program files/common files/microsoft/imei14/shared/imeklmg.exe /uninstall /JPN /log"
   "c:/program files/common files/microsoft/imei14/shared/imeklmg.exe /uninstall /KOR /log"
   ```

   Delete all of them.
6. You may also find the same items from step 5 under:

   ```
   HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
   ```

   If so, delete these as well.
7. If you are not confident with modifying the registry you may do the following instead of steps 2-6: deselect the above mentioned startup commands by doing this:

   1. Start > Control Panel > Administrative tools > System configuration
   2. In the System Configuration window go to the Startup tab
   3. Uncheck all items called "Microsoft Office IMEI 2010" that have the paths from step 5 under the "command" column
   4. You can always come back and re-check these items if you need to
8. Restart your computer

Hopefully after restarting you will no longer have the additional keyboards.

Comment: Worked like a charm! +1!

Comment: after this i also had to remove them from the keyboards  after reboot (where they did not show before!)

Comment: Thx a lot for a this.