# Chinese input apears after office 2010 updates

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, input-languages

My problem-related system config is:

```
Windows 7 Ultimate x64 Eng.

Microsoft Office 2010.

Russian proofing tools for office 2010.
```

I have no idea why, but, presumably, after installing some system or office updates and restarting the computer, I've got a Chinese language as a keyboard input option, and I don't know how to remove it.

It is not listed neither in Office Language Preferences utility, nor in the "Text Services and Input Languages" control dialog. But it does appear in the input options, along with EN, RU, UA I have defined for myself.

Any idea on how to rid my system of a "Chinese invasion"?

Comment: It appears I have a similar problem only I have "Japanese and Korean invasion" :D Did you happen to find a way to fix this?

Comment: @tftd - on one of two machines - yes. But through Language Preferences utility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Self installing East Asian language set. How to remove Asian languages from a language bar?](https://superuser.com/questions/199553/self-installing-east-asian-language-set-how-to-remove-asian-languages-from-a-la/234050#234050)

This guy's solution fixed my problem.. It will probably do it for you too.
Please add +1 to him if it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem on one of my machines I opened a Microsoft Office Language Preferences application from

Start Menu\Programs\Microsoft Office\Microsoft Office 2010 Tools

and removed all occurrences of Chines. This has fixed the problem on my desktop Win 7 (since the languages were indeed listed there), but did not on Win7 laptop (not listed), so the solution is not universal.

Comment: "yellow" languages?  is this a joke?

Comment: Ok, removed =) Yes, it was a joke. Make sure you votedown "Snowhite and the huntsman" movie when it comes out on IMBD.

Comment: Too bad.. the languages are not listed on my machine...  :/