# Self-installed Chinese languages in language bar remain despite deleting their registry keys

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-word, keyboard-layout, language

My Windows 10 had suddenly entries of three Chinese languages in the language bar, without me having them installed.

[image]

They are not present in the keyboard layout, so I cannot uninstall them.

[image]

The culprit may be related to MS Word because in its proofing language section, `Chinese(Taiwan)` has appeared without me having installed it.
[image]

However, this may just be a side effect of other system options because in the MS Word language options, Chinese does not appear.

[image]

I have seen [this](https://superuser.com/questions/187845/different-available-keyboard-layouts-in-language-bar-and-text-services-and-input) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/199553/self-installing-east-asian-language-set-how-to-remove-asian-languages-from-a-la) old thread but I am not able to translate the suggested solutions into a Win10 environment. I was neither able to locate the mentioned registry keys nor the `Office 2010 installed IMEs` in the corresponding Microsoft Word 365 environment.

I installed Chinese/Taiwan as a language option via `Windows display language` - it appeared as a fourth Chinese language entry in the language bar, so uninstalling it afterward, did not solve the problem.

[This thread was marked as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/957552/how-to-delete-a-keyboard-layout-in-windows-10/1340511#1340511), alas it is not. The first method of the supposed duplicate answer does not work, as I explained because the Chinese languages are not listed as language options.

The second method looked promising. Indeed, under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Keyboard Layout\Preload` (but not in the other three mentioned registries) were three Chinese keyboard codes listed. I deleted them and restarted. The Chinese keys are now deleted...

[image]

but the three Chinese entries still exist in the language bar. [image]

While scrutinizing the options in Setting, I noticed that the languages are also mentioned under advanced keyboard settings but you can only change here their hotkeys.

[image]

**Update**
This problem disappeared after an unspecified Windows update without me doing anything specific. Case closed.
(For me.)
(I hope.)

Comment: "The culprit is most likely MS Word" - Can you provide a screenshot of the languages that Microsoft Word believes to be installed?  Additionally, have you tried to uninstall Office (then reinstall it), since you believe that to be the culprit?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but on second thought, Word may just reflect some system changes (see update). I work with Word 98% of my working time, it is a well-established and personalized installation linked with other programs, and I will not uninstall and then not be able to work for days because new problems arise after the reinstallation. So, this is out of the question.

Comment: If you are unwilling to perform that simple test then I will be unable to help you.

Comment: Due to the gold tag I have in Windows 10 I am indeed the reason the question is reopened.  You will want to be more willing to try solutions and/or provide information otherwise your question will eventually be closed again. **I have one suggestion but won't be able to research it for at least 36 hours.**

Comment: Thank you for looking into this. It is of no urgency - the main problem is that I switch input languages with a keyboard shortcut, and the three unnecessary language entries interfere here.

Answer (score 1):

The preceding answers did not yield a solution for me.
This below could be the answer(it was for me). 
Please save/export the current Keys prior to delete them.

Review this or similar Registry Keys below(they could be sightly different) and delete them:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\TIP{B115690A-EA02-48D5-A231-E3578D2FDF80}\LanguageProfile\0x00000404{0AEC109C-7E96-11D4-B2EF-0080C882687E}]
"Description"="Microsoft Hong Kong Cantonese"
"IconFile"="C:\Windows\System32\IME\IMETC\ImTCTip.DLL"
"IconIndex"=dword:00000006

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\TIP{B115690A-EA02-48D5-A231-E3578D2FDF80}\LanguageProfile\0x00000404{0B883BA0-C1C7-11D4-87F9-0080C882687E}]
"Description"="Microsoft New Quick"
"IconFile"="C:\Windows\System32\IME\IMETC\ImTCTip.DLL"
"IconIndex"=dword:00000004

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\TIP{B115690A-EA02-48D5-A231-E3578D2FDF80}\LanguageProfile\0x00000404{F3BA907A-6C7E-11D4-97FA-0080C882687E}]
"Description"="Microsoft New ChangJie"
"IconFile"="C:\Windows\System32\IME\IMETC\ImTCTip.DLL"
"IconIndex"=dword:00000002

I hope this helps, please upvote if this answers your issue.

Best regards

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, after several months a Windows update removed the non-installed languages (and added another, unrelated problem, sigh). One day, they were simply gone without me doing anything specific. So, I cannot test this but maybe someone else might benefit from it. Or, shudder, the problem comes back to haunt me again.

Comment: As I stated, at least for me this was the answer and I highly suspect due to the specific Chinese Languages listed that it was the same.
Took me a bit to figure.

Please post your new inquire and feel free to share the link it for us to help.

This was most likely another Windows Update inflicted issue as you probably suspected.

Best regards,

Comment: Thank you so much for your post. I really appreciate it. After a long time, you have helped me solve my problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra language from:

Regedit
Computer\HKEY_USERS.DEFAULT\Keyboard Layout\Preload

Language CODE
https://www.science.co.il/language/Locale-codes.php

[Regestry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCFs7.png)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. There were indeed three entries for the Chinese language. I delete the keys, restarted but the Chinese language options still remain in the language bar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option, if deleting the keys does not work. Again, please save/export the current keys prior to modifying them.

Review this or similar Registry keys below (they could be sightly different) and delete them:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\TIP{B115690A-EA02-48D5-A231-E3578D2FDF80}\LanguageProfile\0x00000404{0AEC109C-7E96-11D4-B2EF-0080C882687E}]
"Description"="Microsoft Hong Kong Cantonese"
"IconFile"="C:\Windows\System32\IME\IMETC\ImTCTip.DLL"
"IconIndex"=dword:00000006``

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\TIP{B115690A-EA02-48D5-A231-E3578D2FDF80}\LanguageProfile\0x00000404{0B883BA0-C1C7-11D4-87F9-0080C882687E}]
"Description"="Microsoft New Quick"
"IconFile"="C:\Windows\System32\IME\IMETC\ImTCTip.DLL"
"IconIndex"=dword:00000004``

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\TIP{B115690A-EA02-48D5-A231-E3578D2FDF80}\LanguageProfile\0x00000404{F3BA907A-6C7E-11D4-97FA-0080C882687E}]
"Description"="Microsoft New ChangJie"
"IconFile"="C:\Windows\System32\IME\IMETC\ImTCTip.DLL"
"IconIndex"=dword:00000002
```

Inside of each one of the Language keys:

1. Right-click → New → Dword (32-bit) Value
2. Inside that value, type "Enable" and leave the value as `0x00000000` (0)

That should effectively leave the language as disabled.